# Изменить значение ползунка при выборе элемента списка

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как сделать чтобы при выборе пункта из списка должны меняться значения ползунков? Т.е. выбирая пункт `value0` должны поменяться значения ползунков на соответствующие значения массива `arr0[]`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr0 = [5, -3, -2, 0];
        var arr1 = [6, 8, 0, 1];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mylist" class="form-control">
        <option value="value0">value0</option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="apply">

    <input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="0">
    <input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="1">
    <input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="2">
    <input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="3">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function input() {
  var arr = [[5, -3, -2, 0], [6, 8, 0, 1]];
  document.getElementById('mylist').oninput = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('ranges').getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++){
      document.getElementById('input'+i).value = arr[this.value][i];
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<body onload="input()">
<div>
  <select id="mylist" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">value0</option>
    <option value="1">value1</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="ranges">
  <div><input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="input0"></div>
  <div><input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="input1"></div>
  <div><input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="input2"></div>
  <div><input type="range" title="0" class="control" id="input3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Prahvessor, переделал на один JavaScript :)

Comment: querySelector("#mylist"), querySelector('input') удобнее

Comment: @JK_Action, для кого как )